# Why was this question migrated to meta, when it is not a question about the main site?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, migration

I noticed a question, [Is there a thesaurus which takes more than one word as an input?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1673/is-there-a-thesaurus-which-takes-more-than-one-word-as-an-input) and I read it trying to understand why it was on meta. After I read it, I noticed that it doesn't suit on meta because it's not a question about the main site; if it were a question such as "When citing a source in my answer, how should I cite it?" then it would be appropriate for the meta site.

The meta site is not a second class site where English questions that don't suit the main site are migrated; it's a site for questions about the main site. If a question doesn't suit the main site doesn't mean it suits another site (including the meta site); it doesn't mean the question necessarily needs to be migrated to any site (as many closed questions show).
Questions about posts seen on the main sites are fine on meta, as any question about features seen (or desired) in the main site is.

Comment: Well, I've voted to close it on meta (not migrate it back to main!). It may be a matter of interest to many here, but so are the winning numbers in next week's lottery. Just because this particular one seems more "interesting" to relatively sophisticated users, doesn't mean it's any more suitable than *"What's the best dictionary/grammar guide/linguistics primer?".*

Comment: I thought we wanted to silently migrate resource requests to meta. Or is it a recent development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am adding this answer to avoid the question get bumped from the Community user.

The question is now closed.